# Postgres keeps complaining about the EXCEPTION keyword

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

According to the `43.6.8. Trapping Errors` topic in [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html) Postgres Documentation, the correct syntax for handling exceptions is:

```
BEGIN;
-- SQL Statement
EXCEPTION WHEN Others THEN 
    -- Exception Handling Logic
END;
```

This is while when I use this syntax in `pgAdmin`, it keeps complaining about the keyword `EXCEPTION`.

My Query is:

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO TestTable (id) VALUES(3);
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION WHEN Others THEN 
        ROLLBACK;
END;
```

And the error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"
LINE 4:  EXCEPTION WHEN Others THEN 
         ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 57
```

I don't understand what could be possibly wrong with this SQL Code. If this is not the right way to handle exceptions, then how can I implement something similar?

UPDATE: This is NOT Aurora Postgres. I am using Standard Postgres.

Comment: The chapter seems to be about "PL/pgSQL" in functions. Are you using this in a function?

Comment: EXCEPTION is not SQL, it's PL/pgSQL. And most of your PL/pgSQL code is missing, could you share the complete function/procedure?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: That was my actual confusion, I actually didn't know about and I was thinking similar to MSSQL or MariaDB/MySQL, Postgres has implemented just another dialect of SQL that can use out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you quote is the PL/pgSQL documentation, but you have to enter SQL in the query tool. These are different languages, so what would be correct PL/pgSQL causes an error.

If you want to use PL/pgSQL, you have to create a function or procedure, or you could use it in a `DO` statement in SQL.

There are two more problems with your code:

- there cannot be a semicolon after `BEGIN`, so you must have mis-quoted the documentation
- you cannot use a transaction management statement like `COMMIT` in a block with an exception handler

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after posting the question. But can I ask you an additional question? Do you think (like I do) that particularly in Postgres, the `Rollback` is pretty useless? Since when there is an error, Postgres aborts the transaction so that means I would never need to catch the exception and roll back the transaction myself. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you got that right. Very often, when people want to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in PL/pgSQL code, it is actually not necessary.

Comment: Thank you Laurenze, I have recently moved from MSSQL and MariaDB to Postgres. It is a great database but with some peculiarities (which I guess later when I get used to it won't be peculiar anymore)

Answer (score 2):

You say that you are using PgAdmin, so i presume that you are trying to run this code using a query tool window?

In which case you need to place everything within a `DO` like this:

```
do $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testtable (id) VALUES(1);
    INSERT INTO testtable (id) VALUES(2);
    INSERT INTO testtable (id) VALUES(1);
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN Others THEN 
    RAISE NOTICE 'error occurred';
END; $$
```

Note that there is no need for a commit or a rollback.  If you try this code, assuming id is a primary key, you will find that nothing has been inserted.  PostgreSQL automatically treats all the statements as one transaction, and rolls them all back, when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you, I asked Laurenze Albe this question in a comment and I'd like to ask you the same. Do you think (like I do) that particularly in Postgres, the `Rollback` is pretty useless? Since when there is an error, Postgres aborts the transaction so that means I would never need to catch the exception and roll back the transaction myself. Am I right?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Yes and no.  Yes you often don't need transactions, but no this doesn't mean you shouldn't catch the errors.  IMHO you should always track and log all errors.

Comment: It's true that errors should be logged for troubleshooting purposes, but my question is particularly about committing and rolling back. My concern is that, if I leave the transaction unattended so that it would be aborted on an error then the transaction is technically aborted! In this case what would be the difference between Aborted and Rollbacked?

Comment: None.  Internally PostgreSQL performs a `ROLLBACK`

Answer (score -1):

You can refer [here](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/library/error-handling-in-postgresql) to get an idea on how to handle exceptions in PostgreSQL.

Here's the pseudocode(from same link), it might give you an idea:

```
select version() as postgresql_version
$Body$
declare
begin
    -- statements;
exception
    when condition [or condition...] then
       handle_exception;
   [when others then
       handle_other_exceptions;
   ]
end;
$Body$
```